# Push data using service, but can't get pushed value after switching pages

Tags: angular

I have component structure like this

- Parent Component (card-list)
- Child (Card)
- Child (detail-card)
- Child (Form)
- service

I try to push data from FormComponent to service and it works, but if I switch to another page(CardList Component). I can't get the same data from the service, just my default array, and can't find the data that was previously pushed. I don't know why it happens, I need some help
My code like this

formComponent

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit  {
 
  constructor(
              private accountService: AccountsService,
              private fb:FormBuilder,
              
  userForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
   
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      'id': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'name': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      })
    })
  }


    onCreateAccount() {
    this.accountService.account(this.userForm.value);
    console.log(this.userForm);
    console.log(this.accountService.accounts);
    
  }
```

AccountsService

```
export class AccountsService {
    accounts = [
        {
          id: 1234556,
          name: 'Jhon ',
        },
      ];

      account(userData){
      if (userData){
        this.accounts.push(userData)
      }
    }

    getDataId(id: number) {
      return this.accounts.find(acc => acc.id == id)
    }
```

card-list

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountsService } from '../account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-list',
  templateUrl: './card-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-list.component.css'],
  providers: [AccountsService]
})
export class CardListComponent implements OnInit {

  accounts: {id:number, }[] = [];

  constructor(private accountsService: AccountsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.accounts = this.accountsService.accounts;
    console.log(this.accounts)

  }
```

Comment: In your `card-list` component you provide `[AccountService]` - do you provide it in any of the children? (ie Card/DetailCard/Form)?

Comment: ya there is children `card` and `card-list` looping the child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

service is a Singleton, but in your `CardListComponent` you set `providers: [AccountsService]`
what's means you created another instance of this service, so this instance is not update with the new data...
just remove this line and make sure `AccountService` is provide only once.
the default of angular
`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` above the the line `export class AccountService`

Comment: This isn't a correct answer given his/her component hierarchy.  CardList is a parent of the form - and thus provided in a parent, it should be injectable to the child. The problem is that they injected it into a different parent lower in the hierarchy, as explained in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Angular looks up the component tree to find the first component providing the service.  If your Card-List Component and Card component both provide the service, then the service created in the Card Component will trump the service created in the Card-List component.

Sometimes its good to have service provided at the component level - if you had a service that you wanted to do business logic per card, and maintain card state, then you'd want to provide that service at the component level.  All children of that card will inject only the service with state relative to that card.

In this case, you provide a service at the card-list level, and the card level.  This means that the form looks up its tree and finds the service provided at the card level, and that service modifies its state.  This shields the service provided by the card-list level, which never gets modified because its child (card) is the one injected into all of the forms.

This is solvable in two ways:

1. Remove all providers of `AccountsService` and let it live in root.  This will render the service global in scope and will retain all state throughout the lifecycle of your application.
2. Remove the provider only from the card component.  The service will maintain state relative to the card list, which means you should extract and handle the state before the card-list is destroyed.  Conversely, you can have multiple card lists on the screen without them interfering with each other.